# App for anotating video

Tags: video, bookmark, video-player, text

I am looking for am Android app for watching videos and add notes to specific timestamps.
I could use VLC with bookmarks, but then I would only be able to add labels while what I need is to add complete paragraphs of texts. Also I would like to have a visual aid to see where are all the notes like in a timeline.
I can do all that in Transcribe! But it is only for desktop.